# How to add a trial period for an item using Paypal PHP SDK?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm working on an application to charge my users on a monthly basis for a subscription using this SDK: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Here's the code:

```
$total = $price;
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
$item = new Item();
$item->setName($productName)->setQuantity(1)->setPrice($price)->setCurrency($currency);
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array(
    $item
));
$details = new Details();
$details->setSubtotal($price);
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency($currency)->setTotal($total)->setDetails($details);
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)->setItemList($itemList)->setDescription('Pay For ' . $productName)->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($returnUrl);
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')->setPayer($payer)->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)->setTransactions(array(
    $transaction
));
$payment->create($paypal);
return $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

I want to add a 7-day trial period before the subscription starts. Using the Paypal SDK, how do I do it?

Comment: Dumping your code and asking how is not very useful. What have you tried where is it failing?

Comment: I have not found anything that I can try.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-freeTrialRecurringPayments-curl-etc/#step-4-include-a-free-trial-in-a-recurring-payments-profile

Comment: @TrondroMulligan, do you mean you need to process payment after trial period?